# Count highest level of pivot table row

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have this pivot table in Excel and I would like to count only the highest level of the grouped rows. Without using VBA.

[image]

Expected result would be 5.

Comment: couldn't you use a 'countif' function?

Comment: It would be easier to count unique from the data source.  There are many examples on how to do that.

Comment: @sous2817 what would be the condition?

Comment: @ScottCraner don't understand your question since the filters are being applied on the pivot table and not on the data source.

Comment: the only way to do it on the pivot table would be to show the pivot table in tabular form then count the results in the correct column with COUNTA.

Comment: what Scott said...you tell us what the conditions are and someone might help with the formula.